# Is it possible to output table ordered by group and limited per group?

Tags: sqlite, sql-order-by, common-table-expression, window-functions

I have a database with a table of cars, the table has a number of different columns. I need to output the content within that table ordered by the Make of each car, only three cars from each make need to be outputted along side the total from eachh row of car. I also need to have the output ordered in descending order accompanied by a column called Ranking that counts up from 1 to however many outputs there will be.

Below is a sample from my databse table

```
|Timestamp     |Email                    |Name      |Year|Make    |Model    |Car_ID|Judge_ID|Judge_Name|Racer_Turbo|Racer_Supercharged|Racer_Performance|Racer_Horsepower|Car_Overall|Engine_Modifications|Engine_Performance|Engine_Chrome|Engine_Detailing|Engine_Cleanliness|Body_Frame_Undercarriage|Body_Frame_Suspension|Body_Frame_Chrome|Body_Frame_Detailing|Body_Frame_Cleanliness|Mods_Paint|Mods_Body|Mods_Wrap|Mods_Rims|Mods_Interior|Mods_Other|Mods_ICE|Mods_Aftermarket|Mods_WIP|Mods_Overall|
|--------------|-------------------------|----------|----|--------|---------|------|--------|----------|-----------|------------------|-----------------|----------------|-----------|--------------------|------------------|-------------|----------------|------------------|------------------------|---------------------|-----------------|--------------------|----------------------|----------|---------|---------|---------|-------------|----------|--------|----------------|--------|------------|
|8/5/2018 14:10|honoland13@japanpost.jp  |Hernando  |2015|Acura   |TLX      |48    |J04     |Bob       |0          |0                 |2                |2               |4          |4                   |0                 |2            |4               |4                 |2                       |4                    |2                |2                   |2                     |2         |2        |0        |4        |4            |4         |6       |2               |0       |4           |
|8/5/2018 15:11|nlighterness2q@umn.edu   |Noel      |2015|Jeep    |Wrangler |124   |J02     |Carl      |0          |6                 |4                |2               |4          |6                   |6                 |4            |4               |4                 |6                       |6                    |6                |6                   |6                     |4         |6        |6        |6        |6            |6         |4       |6               |4       |6           |
|8/5/2018 17:10|eguest47@microsoft.com   |Edan      |2015|Lexus   |Is250    |222   |J05     |Adrian    |0          |0                 |0                |0               |0          |0                   |0                 |0            |6               |6                 |6                       |0                    |0                |6                   |6                     |6         |0        |0        |0        |0            |0         |0       |0               |0       |4           |
|8/5/2018 17:34|hchilley40@fema.gov      |Hieronymus|1993|Honda   |Civic eG |207   |J06     |Aaron     |0          |0                 |2                |2               |2          |2                   |2                 |2            |0               |4                 |2                       |2                    |2                |2                   |2                     |2         |4        |2        |2        |0            |0         |0       |2               |2       |0           |
|8/5/2018 14:30|nnowick3d@tuttocitta.it  |Nickolas  |2016|Ford    |Mystang  |167   |J02     |Carl      |0          |0                 |2                |2               |0          |2                   |2                 |0            |0               |0                 |0                       |2                    |0                |2                   |2                     |2         |0        |0        |2        |0            |0         |0       |0               |0       |2           |
|8/5/2018 16:12|mdearl39@amazon.co.uk    |Martin    |2013|Hyundai |Gen coupe|159   |J04     |Bob       |0          |0                 |2                |0               |0          |0                   |2                 |0            |0               |0                 |0                       |2                    |0                |2                   |2                     |0         |2        |0        |2        |0            |0         |0       |0               |0       |0           |
|8/5/2018 17:00|alynamg@blogtalkradio.com|Aldridge  |2009|Infiniti|G37      |20    |J06     |Aaron     |2          |0                 |2                |2               |0          |0                   |2                 |0            |0               |2                 |2                       |2                    |2                |2                   |2                     |2         |2        |2        |4        |2            |2         |0       |2               |0       |2           |
|8/5/2018 16:11|abowton3k@spiegel.de     |Ambros    |2009|Honda   |Oddesy   |178   |J06     |Aaron     |2          |0                 |2                |2               |2          |2                   |2                 |0            |4               |4                 |2                       |2                    |2                |4                   |4                     |4         |2        |2        |         |6            |4         |4       |6               |4       |6           |
|8/5/2018 17:29|qesterbrookn@bandcamp.com|Quincy    |2012|Hyundai |Celoster |30    |J04     |Bob       |0          |0                 |2                |2               |2          |2                   |2                 |4            |6               |6                 |4                       |2                    |4                |4                   |6                     |6         |4        |0        |2        |0            |0         |0       |2               |2       |4           |
```

The expected output is something like this below

```
|Ranking |Car_ID|Year   |Make  |Model      |Total|
|--------|------|-------|------|-----------|-----|
|1       |48    |2015   |Acura |TLX        |89   |
|2       |66    |2012   |Acura |MDX        |75   |
|3       |101   |2022   |Acura |TLX        |70   |
|4       |22    |2011   |Chevy |Camaro     |112  |
|5       |40    |2015   |Chevy |Corvette   |99   |
|6       |205   |2022   |Chevy |Corvette   |66   |
|7       |111   |2006   |Ford  |Mustang    |94   |
|8       |97    |2003   |Ford  |GT         |88   |
|9       |71    |2008   |Ford  |Fiesta ST  |80   |
```

Here's the command I've been been able to put together which does something similar to what I need, but I can't figure out how to do the ranking column and order by descending from the total.

```
SELECT Car_ID, Year, Make, Model, Racer_Turbo + Racer_Supercharged + ... + Mods_Overall FROM Carstable order by Make limit 3;
```

This query command only returned three results instead of all, I also can't figure out where to put the DESC keyword in the command in order to have them listed in descending order based on the total column or how to do the ranking column as well. Any ideas?

Comment: You should normalise your table!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a CTE which returns the column `Total` for each row and `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to pick the first 3 rows for each `Make` and to create the column `Ranking`:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, 
       Racer_Turbo + Racer_Supercharged + Racer_Performance + Racer_Horsepower + 
       Car_Overall + 
       Engine_Modifications + Engine_Performance + Engine_Chrome + Engine_Detailing + Engine_Cleanliness + 
       Body_Frame_Undercarriage + Body_Frame_Suspension + Body_Frame_Chrome + Body_Frame_Detailing + Body_Frame_Cleanliness + 
       Mods_Paint + Mods_Body + Mods_Wrap + Mods_Rims + Mods_Interior + Mods_Other + Mods_ICE + Mods_Aftermarket + Mods_WIP + Mods_Overall Total
  FROM carstable
)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Make, Total DESC) Ranking,
       Car_ID, Year, Make, Model, Total
FROM (SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Make ORDER BY Total) rn FROM cte) 
WHERE rn <= 3
ORDER BY Make, Total DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=1e4d1faccf8f544df4936097e10e1766).